# How to update existing Salesforce User details in Ping User Provisioning

Tags: salesforce, ping, jit, provisioning

We have Ping setup for Auto User Provisioning and its working for new users with configured User attributes as expected.

Now, If I want to update existing salesforce users details, we changed Outbound Channel Attribute Mappings in Ping, and expected it to update. But it didnt update any user in Salesforce automatically.

We also verified by logging in to Salesforce through SSO link, No change of User details yet.

Is this doable in Ping or JIT in Salesforce is mandatory?